# Get matched pattern value in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing some transliteration with java and everything works great, but it would be nice to have matched pattern. Is it possible?

For example:

for surname **GULEVSKAIA** I generate such pattern

```
(^g+(yu|u|y)l+(io|e|ye|yo|jo|ye)(v|b|w)+(s|c)+(k|c)+a(ya|ia|ja|a|y)(a)*)
```

can I somehow get information, that actually matched

g

u

l

e

...

etc

As you can see, sometimes it is NOT one letter.

Comment: When you have things in `( )` in a regex, it defines a "capture group" that you can then query with `Matcher` methods.  See this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html.

Comment: Thank you. So simple... I have to move all chars (like g or a) to groups, but it is not a big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this , once pattern is matched , retrive the macthed string using group() method of Matcher class passing 0 as value. then convert that string to chars array and print those characters like below

```
  String line = "gulevskaia";
  String pattern = "(^g+(yu|u|y)l+(io|e|ye|yo|jo|ye)(v|b|w)+(s|c)+(k|c)+a(ya|ia|ja|a|y)(a)*)";


  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
     char chars[] =m.group(0).toCharArray();
     for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++)
         System.out.println(chars[i]);

  }
```